# How is Google specifying that their logo will be added from the Facebook Share Link?

Tags: html, facebook

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com&t=aFlickrPicture" target="_blank">SHARE</a>
```

When you click share and are logged into facebook, you will see the google image loaded as a thumbnail.

However, all that is specified in the share link is www.google.com and type flicker image.

I did not see any of the "Open Graph Tags" in the page source of google.com ?

Thanks.

**EDIT** - actually you can remove the type and it still displays an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo is the only image in that page, so they don't need to specify anything to add it to the sharer.

Comment: Yes, if you don't define what thumbnail to use, facebook will probably choose one for you, I remember having issues sometimes with that, but usually, it works.